# cannot find opencv module while running python file

Tags: python, opencv, pip

While importing cv2 in jupyter notebook it works fine. But while importing cv2 in vs code it throws this error: `ImportError: No module named cv2`. Same error occus when I run .py file using command prompt.
I am running the latest version of python and anaconda.
I installed opencv using `pip install opencv-python`.
I tried installing it using `conda install -c conda-forge opencv` but it thow this error "Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve".

Edit:
I used pip install opencv-contrib-python and it works fine in vs code using anaconda navigator but it doesn't work for python file using windows command prompt.

Comment: Run `pip freeze` in your command prompt and check if `opencv-python` shows up

Answer (score 0):

First, try installing from [anaconda channel](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/opencv) `conda install -c anaconda opencv`. If the issue remains the same when you do `import cv2` in VS Code Terminal, then please try the following.

Create a new conda environment, use command `conda env create -f env.yml`, and use the content below your `env.yml` file.

```
name: opencv-env
channels:
  - defaults
  - anaconda
dependencies:
  - opencv
```